# Spring integration Header Enricher does work in chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This is my spring integration case:

1) ftp adapter to download a pdf file

2) pdf2TextTransformer transform pdf to text by using pdfbox

3) pdfText2CsvTransformer transform text to csv

I add an enricher in the chain, however, seems header doesn't propagate to myErrorChannel, anyone can tell me why?

Here is my debug log, header file_originalFile doesn't propagate to myErrorChannel

```
][Headers={file_originalFile=D:\projects\DMTP\ftp\local2\6000047256 - Copy - Copy.pdf, file_name=6000047256 - Copy - Copy.pdf, id=a091fe5e-83f3-e48c-4be5-927849dbf31a, timestamp=1501472718172}]
11:45:18.180 DEBUG [task-scheduler-2][org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel] preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload MessageTransformationException content=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3][Headers={id=251c77f0-30e8-e18c-6980-ebfb289f79a4, timestamp=1501472718180}]
11:45:18.180 DEBUG [task-scheduler-2][org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler] ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@56eacc77] received message: [Payload MessageTransformationException content=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3][Headers={id=251c77f0-30e8-e18c-6980-ebfb289f79a4, timestamp=1501472718180}]
file_originalFile:null
MessageHeaders: {id=251c77f0-30e8-e18c-6980-ebfb289f79a4, timestamp=1501472718180}
MessagePayload: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
11:45:18.182 DEBUG [task-scheduler-2][org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler] handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@56eacc77]' produced no reply for request Message: [Payload MessageTransformationException content=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3][Headers={id=251c77f0-30e8-e18c-6980-ebfb289f79a4, timestamp=1501472718180}]
```

here is my configuration:

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cachingSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="ftpClientFactory"/>
</bean>
<int:channel id="ftpChannelIn">
    <int:queue capacity="1"/>
</int:channel>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                                 channel="ftpChannelIn"
                                 session-factory="cachingSessionFactory"
                                 filename-pattern="*.pdf"
                                 auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                 delete-remote-files="true"
                                 remote-directory="/in2"
                                 local-directory="D:/projects/DMTP/ftp/local2">
    <!--<int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>-->
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:chain input-channel="ftpChannelIn">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <file:file-to-bytes-transformer/>
    <int:transformer ref="pdf2TextTransformer"/>
    <int:transformer ref="pdfText2CsvTransformer"/>
    <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
            remote-directory="/out"
            session-factory="cachingSessionFactory"
            remote-filename-generator="filenameGenerator"/>
</int:chain>


<int:channel id="ftpChannelOut">
</int:channel>
<bean id="filenameGenerator" class="file.DatedDirectoryFactory "/>
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
<int:channel id="myErrorChannel"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorLogger"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ErrorMessage` is built in the Poller and it is based on the exception:

```
try {
    getMessagingTemplate().send(errorChannel, getErrorMessageStrategy().buildErrorMessage(t, null));
            sent = true;
}
```

There is no any info about original headers.

Your headers, in particular `<int:header name="foo" value="bar"/>` is presented on the downstream `requestMessage`. Typically, when exception happens in the Integration Component, the `MessagingException` is thrown.
In your case it is `MessageTransformationException`. That kind of exception has `failedMessage` property. This is exactly your `requestMessage` what is "guilty" in the error. And, as you understand, already here you can get access to you headers - `MessagingException.getFailedMessage().getHeaders()get("foo")`. And, of course, `file_originalFile` will be available here as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your transformers are returning `Message<?>` then they are responsible for copying the headers; the framework assumes that. If your transformers are POJO, and return just the transformed payload (the recommended programming model), the framework will take care of propagating the headers.

Turn on debug logging to examine the message flow; if you still think it "doesn't work", explain in more detail and edit the question to show the log.

BTW, "doesn't work" is not an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: Thanks, Gary
My transform is POJO, and I added my debug log for your information, would you help to check why  header file_originalFile doesn't propagate to myErrorChannel?

Comment: Also see my answer.

Comment: Sigh; as you can see "does not work" is a completely inadequate explanation of the problem; you now added an important part, about the error channel. Never, never, never ask a question with "does not work", without further explanation. Thanks @ArtemBilan .